# How to update Tkinter window every time image is processed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI that will display an image that is taken every 10 seconds and it's processed counter part. I'm having trouble getting the GUI window to update the two images when they get overridden in the file system.

Here's the code I have so far

```
import cv2
import threading
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os
from tkinter import *  
import os
from PIL import ImageTk,Image 
root = Tk()  
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 2000, height = 2000)  
canvas.pack()  
execution_path = os.getcwd()
inimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(execution_path , "test.jpg"))) 
outimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(execution_path , "testnew.jpg")))
def capture():
    print("Capturing...")
    videoCaptureObject = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret,frame = videoCaptureObject.read()
    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",frame)
    print("Done capturing.")
    print("Finding")
    totalPersons = 0
    detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "test.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "testnew.jpg"))
    for eachObject in detections:
     if(eachObject["name"] == "person"):
        totalPersons += 1
    print("Total persons " + str(totalPersons))

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
execution_path = os.getcwd()
detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel("fastest")


def run():
    threading.Timer(10.0, run).start()
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=inimg) 
    canvas.create_image(750, 500, anchor=SW, image=outimg)
    root.mainloop() 
    capture()
run()
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use
`root.update_idletasks()`
to update tkinter  GUI window.